# Gitorious socket timeout on repo creation

Tags: timeout, stomp, gitorious

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a new repository with gitorious:

```
Timeout::Error (execution expired):
  /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:60:in `socket'
  stomp (1.1) lib/stomp/connection.rb:42:in `initialize'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/adapters/stomp.rb:28:in `initialize'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/gateway.rb:112:in `new'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/gateway.rb:112:in `connection'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/gateway.rb:300:in `publish'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/gateway.rb:149:in `execute_filter_chain'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/gateway.rb:299:in `publish'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/gateway.rb:298:in `publish'
  vendor/plugins/activemessaging/lib/activemessaging/message_sender.rb:21:in `publish'
  app/models/repository.rb:356:in `post_repo_creation_message'
  vendor/rails/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:178:in `send'
```

I've checked and stomp is definitely running, telnet connects fine.

What could the problem be?

gems I currently have installed:

```
abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0)
actionpack (3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.0)
activeresource (3.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.0)
arel (1.0.1)
BlueCloth (1.0.1)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.0.0)
cgi_multipart_eof_fix (2.5.0)
chronic (0.2.3)
daemons (1.1.0)
diff-lcs (1.1.2)
echoe (4.3.1)
erubis (2.6.6)
eventmachine (0.12.10)
facter (1.5.8)
fastthread (1.0.7)
ffi (0.6.3)
foreman (0.8.0)
gcal4ruby (0.5.5)
gdata4ruby (0.1.5)
gem_plugin (0.2.3)
gemcutter (0.6.1)
geoip (0.8.7)
hoe (2.6.2)
i18n (0.4.1)
json (1.4.6)
json_pure (1.4.6)
mail (2.2.6.1)
mime-types (1.16)
mongrel (1.1.5)
oniguruma (1.1.0)
passenger (2.2.15)
plist (3.1.0)
polyglot (0.3.1)
puppet (2.6.1)
rack (1.2.1, 1.0.1)
rack-mount (0.6.13)
rack-test (0.5.6)
rails (3.0.0)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (0.8.7)
rdiscount (1.3.1.1)
RedCloth (4.2.3)
rmagick (2.13.1)
rspec (1.3.0)
rspec-rails (1.3.2)
ruby-hmac (0.4.0)
ruby-openid (2.1.8)
ruby-yadis (0.3.4)
rubyforge (2.0.4)
sqlite3-ruby (1.2.5)
stomp (1.1)
stompserver (0.9.9)
term-ansicolor (1.0.5)
textpow (0.10.1)
thor (0.14.2, 0.13.8)
treetop (1.4.8)
tzinfo (0.3.23)
```

---

In message_processing, I also have:

```
Timed out trying to send the message #<OpenStruct body="{\"target_id\":90,\"arguments\":[\"18c/021/54f8f3621c153f490823e37ebbec21d504.git\"],\"command\":\"create_git_repository\",\"target_class\":\"Repository\"}", headers={:persistent=>true}> to destination create_repo via broker default
```